# how to change the value of input box just for display in html 5 web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textfield in which i am entering data i want that if user enter 1000 then it show 1,000 in textfield but this same value 1000 is also used in calculations further so how to solve this if user enter 1000 then just for display it show 1,000 and if we use in calcualtion then same var shows 1000 for calculating.

```
  <HTML>
  <body>
  <input type="text" id="test" value="" />
  </body>

   <script>


     var c=document.getElementById(test);
   </script>
  </html>
```

so if c user enter 1000 then it should dispaly 1,000 for dispaly one and if user uses in script

```
     var test=c
```

then test should show 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns either `null` or a reference to the unique element, in this case a `input` element. Input elements have an attribute `value` which contains their current value (as a string).

So you can use

```
var test = parseInt(c.value, 10);
```

to get the **current value**. This means that if you didn't use any predefined value `test` will be `NaN`.

However, this will be evaluated only once. In order to change the value you'll need to add an event listener, which handles changes to the input:

```
// or c.onkeyup
c.onchange = function(e){
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: i want to dispay the inputed data like 1,000 in textfields but not to change the actual value of id

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone: In five days you asked 11 questions. My answer already covers the basic features you need to use, every further information can be found very easily. Instead of commenting on existing answers you should edit your question if you notice that people don't get what you actually want.

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone: No, and __now__ I never will. You don't even have patience for 5 minutes? Wow.

Comment: if c.value === "1,000" then parseInt(test, 10) === 1 not 1000, and other than the suggestion to use event handler for commas, there is no suggestion as to how. And this got accepted as answer? Not knocking you Zeta, just confused by the OP

Comment: @Xotic750: `c.value === "1000"`, and `result` should be `"1,000"`. It's not overly simple to understand the OP. but he notes it in his last paragraph: *"so if c user enter 1000 then it should dispaly 1,000 for dispaly one and if user uses in script "* translates to "if the user enters `1000` into the input, I want to display it as `1,000`". However, I wouldn't accept this answer either, since I wouldn't even ask this question with so little effort.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing form where Zeta left:

```
var testValue = parseInt(c.value);
```

Now let's compose the display as you want it: 1,000

```
var textDecimal = c.value.substr(c.value.length-3); // last 3 characters returned
var textInteger = c.value.substr(0,c.value.length-3); // characters you want to appear to the right   of the coma
var textFinalDisplay = textInteger + ',' + textDecimal

alert(textFinalDisplay);
```

Now you have the display saved in textFinalDisplay as a string, and the actual value saved as an integer in c.value

Comment: Note: [In some countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system) `,` is actually used to [separate thousands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousands_separator#Digit_grouping).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="test" value=""></input>
<button type="button" id="get">Get value</input>

var test = document.getElementById("test"),
    button = document.getElementById("get");

function doCommas(evt) {
    var n = evt.target.value.replace(/,/g, "");
        d = n.indexOf('.'),
        e = '',
        r = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    if (d !== -1) {
        e = '.' + n.substring(d + 1, n.length);
        n = n.substring(0, d);
    }

    while (r.test(n)) {
        n = n.replace(r, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }

    evt.target.value = n + e;
}

function getValue() {
    alert("value: " + test.value.replace(/,/g, ""));
}

test.addEventListener("keyup", doCommas, false);
button.addEventListener("click", getValue, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uvZ4T/)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the actual value from variable x

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function abc(){
            var x = document.getElementById('txt').value;               
            var y = x/1000;
            var z = y+","+ x.toString().substring(1);
            document.getElementById('txt').value = z;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt" value="" onchange = "abc()"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with integer numbers on Firefox (Linux). You can access the "non-commaed"-value using the function "intNumValue()":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    String.prototype.displayIntNum = function()
    {
    var digits = String(Number(this.intNumValue())).split(""); // strip leading zeros
    var displayNum = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<digits.length; i++) {
        if(i && !(i%3)) {
        displayNum.unshift(",");
        }
        displayNum.unshift(digits[digits.length-1-i]);
    }
    return displayNum.join("");
    }
    String.prototype.intNumValue = function() {
    return this.replace(/,/g,"");
    }
    function inputChanged() {
    var e = document.getElementById("numInp");
    if(!e.value.intNumValue().replace(/[0-9]/g,"").length) {
        e.value = e.value.displayIntNum();
    }
    return false;
    }
    function displayValue() {
    alert(document.getElementById("numInp").value.intNumValue());
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="displayValue()">Display value</button>
<p>Input integer value:<input id="numInp" type="text" oninput="inputChanged()">
</body>
</html>
```